# How to access ng-repeat values from the OptGroup

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my HTML code

```
<select id="drplist" ng-model="node.field.name" data-nodrag class="form-control" ng-change="currentColumnInfo(node.field.name,Item.Type,formname)">
                    <optgroup label="{{primaryObjectName}}">
                        <option ng-repeat="Item in columnsList" value="{{Item.name}}" id="{{Item.name}}" ng-selected="true">{{Item.name}}</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="{{object.formName}}" ng-repeat="object in secondaryObjectList">
                        <option ng-repeat="Item in object.fields" value="{{Item.name}}" id="{{Item.name}}">{{Item.name}}</option>

                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

I am getting `node.field.name`, `item.Type`, and `formname` as `undefined` when this ng-change function `ng-change="currentColumnInfo(node.field.name,Item.Type,formname)"` fires; can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference `Item` outside of the `ng-repeat` loop.

I think what you need to do is transform your data structure for `columnsList` and `object.fields` into one data structure, and use the [label group by group for (key, value) in object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) expression for `ng-options`

Comment: i got it, this can be done in normal select tag(ng-options), but how to do it in optgroup?